# When I run the following code, it throws an Exception, why?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

code:

```
public class JniTest {
    static {    
       System.load("/usr/lib/libJniTest.so"); //It run have no exception and true
               //System.loadLibrary("libJniTest");
    }
    public native void sayHello();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(System.getProperties().getProperty("java.library.path"));
    new JniTest().sayHello();
    }
}
```

If use the comments code instead of `"System.load("/usr/lib/libJniTest.so")`, it will throw     exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libJniTest in   java.library.path!
```

I have input

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib in /etc/profile and set vm arguments:
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib
```

Help me, Please!

Comment: Did you tried `System.load(JniTest.class.getClass().getResource("/usr/lib/libJniTest.so").toString());` ?  As I see the *libJniTest.so* is outside your class package.

Comment: If use the comments code instead of "System.load("/usr/lib/libJniTest.so"), it will throw exception

Comment: @Azad That suggestion doesn't begin to make sense. You can't load .so files from JAR files, and you can't load them from URLs either. `getResource()` returns a `URL,` and `load()` requires a path argument, not a URL.

Answer (score 1):

Set VM arguments with :

```
-Djava.library.path="${workspace_loc}/project_name:${env_var:PATH}"
```

and make sure that .so should be in your project folder

Comment: I hava copy the libJniTest.so to the java.library.path directory!

Comment: It throw exception continue, I want restart my computer!

Comment: @lxj There is no 'java.library.path' directory. It is a system property that *you set* to point to *your* libraries.